# How to manipulate hough circles to detect all circles in the given image using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import copy

image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Deepak Padhi/Desktop/download.png')

#cv2.imshow('Filtered_original',image)

image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)

orig_image = np.copy(image)
gray= image[:,:,1]
output=gray.copy()
##cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
##cv2.waitKey(0)

circles=cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, 4.0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(output,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(output,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imshow('detected circles',output)
```

This is the code I used to try and detect all circles in the given image:
[Image of circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGzSW.png)

Which parameter and how should I manipulate to detect the smaller as well as the larger circles? I had tried minRadius and maxRadius to possible values as per both circles, but it didn't work, so I let it reset to default.

It feels like the canny edge detector is actually detecting the smaller circles with the default arguments(100,100), as attached [canny detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iReE.png)

I took the Green plane of the given image:[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vG2y.png)

Comment: well if you would have posted your original input image we could suggest parameters that work but unfortunately you posted a screenshot of the imshow dialog.

Comment: I didn't know about that, Made an edit with the original image, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to first [read the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d).

If you just change the *param1* and *param2* which are thresholds for the Canny edge detector, the **cv2.HoughCircles** works fine.

Here the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('circles.png')

image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)

orig_image = np.copy(image)
gray = image[:, :, 1]
output = gray.copy()

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=20, 
                           minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(output, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(output, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
cv2.imwrite('detected circles.png', output)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I also ask you how you got the values of canny parameters as 50,20? Also, when I performed canny detection with the parameters, it was showing the smaller circles to be detected, as shown in the image attached with the question. If it was detected with 100,100, then how did changing the canny parameters fix the hough transform detection?

Comment: 1 more question: the docs actually state something quite different from the parameters that worked for me: For param1: "Note that HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT uses Scharr algorithm to compute image derivatives, so the threshold value shough normally be higher, such as 300 or normally exposed and contrasty images.     "                            For param2: "The closer it to 1, the better shaped circles algorithm selects. In most cases 0.9 should be fine. If you want get better detection of small circles, you may decrease it to 0.85, 0.8 or even less."   Can you help me with how this differs so much?

Comment: Hi, it all depends on the _cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_. The values 50 and 20 were from trial and error. The docs explain that there is a Canny detector in the Hough implementation.